# Django:AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'was_published_recently'

Tags: django

При воде команды:a.was_published_recently()

Выдается ошибка:AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'was_published_recently'

[image: ошибка и код]

Comment: Проверьте миграции в базу данных. Может забыли сделать

Comment: Перед запуском кода Вы импортировали уже изменённый класс?

Comment: @AlioshcaZ Для методов не требуются миграции, они никак не связаны с БД.

Comment: Ага, попался, фанат хауди хо!